# How to write apple script code to automate daily small task?

Tags: macos, automation, command, applescript

I have found the applescript code on internet, to start a terminal and launch Elasticsearch
the code is

```
tell app "Terminal"
  do script "elasticsearch-5.5.0/bin/./elasticsearch"
end tell
```

It works fine,
now I want to add more stuff on it, I need to open 4 more new tab **not new window** just tab (command + T). and then run different command such as log tail command, start kibana like one after another in each tab.

I am new to applescript and got tired by searching samples and tutorials, can anyone suggest a solution or your idea to achieve the automation.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal's scripting dictionary isn't very good — a lot of '*Apple Event Handler Failed*' errors — but you can manage it with code like the following:

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate

my makeTab("ls -al")
my makeTab("top")
my makeTab("cd ~/Documents")

on makeTab(cmd)
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using {command down}
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script cmd in last tab of front window
    end tell
    delay 0.2
end makeTab
```

Just put whatever commands you want run inside the `makeTab()` call.